# Bitrix24 Virtualbox installation

Tags: bitrix

has anyone else had a similar problem? I'm trying to install Bitrix24 virtual machine downloaded from official website on Virtualbox, but as I do, I run into this error "Please delete legacy parameter mbstring.func_overload.", however, accessing php.ini file from CentOS it shows that the parameter is commented to be disabled. The same error pops up if you make it a value of 0. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the solution myself. If anyone faces the same problem just do the following steps:

- Create a new Virtualbox machine with the Bitrix Virtual environment;
- Create a server;
- Update it to 7.4.4, which is the current latest stable version and already has the mbstring.func_overload removed;
- You can start the installation, you should not run into the same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and just update the version of Bitrix to 7.4.4, problem will be solved.

For people who is not aware how to update

How to update

1. Login using SSH
2. Configure localhost settings
3. Update

that's all